# CiviMail WYSIWYG not working

Tags: wordpress, civimail, ckeditor, wysiwyg

*****UPDATE ADDED 1/22/18-Additonal Settings from Civicrm.settings.php

```
// Additional settings generated by installer:
```

$civicrm_paths['wp.frontend.base']['url'] = 'https://secure.blank.org/';
$civicrm_paths['wp.backend.base']['url'] = 'https://secure.blank.org/wp-admin/';
$civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = 'https://secure.blank.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm';

*****UPDATE ADDED 1/22/18-
Please see the screenshot below.  Could this be the problem? There is not a /secure/ subdirectory. 
The paths should be: 
https://secure.blank.org/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/
not 
https://secure.blank.org/**secure**/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ 
and 
https://secure.blank.org/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ 
not 
https://secure.blank.org/**secure**/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/

I am not seeing where to change this in civicrm.settings.php. Is there another file where this is set?

[image]

****END UPDATE****

We are using Civi 4.7.29 on WordPress 4.9.1

When creating a new mailing in CiviMail, I will select the template and it will be displayed differently in the HTML editor than it should be.  The preview show it correctly. Please see the screen shots below.  I am thinking it is either a paths issue or a permissions issue.  Has this happened to anyone else?  Does anyone have any idea where I can start with resolving it?

[image: HTML EDITOR]
[image: Preview]

These are the ERRORs being shown 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/open.php?q= 
/secure/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/crm-ckeditor-default.js?t=G87D Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What should the permissions be for these two files?
My open.php is 664
My crm-ckeditor-default.js is 644.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly, but I've seen WYSIWYG having problems on one of our sites due to incorrect loading of `[cms.root]` token in Resource URL. To check what's wrong.

- Look for the token populated by clicking on the small help icon on `civicrm/admin/setting/url?reset=1` (Administer -> System Setting -> Resource URL).
- Similarly on `civicrm/admin/setting/path?reset=1` (Administer -> System Setting -> Directories).
- If any of the path looks incorrect, specify it explicitly in your `civicrm.settings.php` file as below.

  ```
  global $civicrm_paths;
  $civicrm_paths['cms.root'] = array(
    'url' => 'http://cms_root_url',
    'path' => '/cms/root/path',
  );
  $civicrm_paths['civicrm.root'] = array(
    'url' => 'http://civicrm_root_url',
    'path' => '/civicrm/root/path',
  );
  $civicrm_paths['civicrm.files'] = array(
    'url' => 'http://civicrm_files_url',
    'path' => '/civicrm/files/path',
  );
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think you got me on the right track. Please see the update I added at the top of the the post.  I hope you can tell me where to fix that, I am not seeing that path with the subdirectory in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Not sure where this originates from (base page?). But you can directly copy the above code part and paste it in `civicrm.settings.php` with your url and path to see if it fixes your issue. It will not be already present in that file. you need to add it.

Comment: The above example only contains the setting for cms.root, but from the screenshot, it seems you need to do it for `civicrm.root` and `civicrm.files`

Comment: Thank you. That worked perfectly for the civicrm.root.  Before I do the same for the civicrm.files, can you tell me what that code should look like?

Comment: Just need to replace cms.root with civicrm.root and civicrm.file. Have updated the answer to the same.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the screenshots it looks like you've installed WP in it's own directory as opposed to the web root.

Starting in Version 4.7.27 CiviCRM will detect if [WP is installed in it's own directory](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

So on new installs we will see a new section in civicrm.settings.php:

```
// Additional settings generated by installer:
$civicrm_paths['wp.frontend.base']['url'] = 'https://wpsub.test/';
$civicrm_paths['wp.backend.base']['url'] = 'https://wpsub.test/wordpress/wp-admin/';
$civicrm_setting['URL Preferences']['userFrameworkResourceURL'] = 'https://wpsub.test/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/';
```

Does you civicrm.settings.php have the above lines?   If this was an upgrade it would not.   The reason for these settings is that the baseurl is different for the front end and back end of a WP site if it's installed in it's own directory.

Comment: Yes it does. It was not any upgrade.  I installed the latest version on a subdomain, then imported our records from the root install.  We wanted to start over fresh.  The lines on my Additional Settings looks like that.  There is no mention of a /secure/ directory. I don't know how that got in there.

Comment: Do the lines have /secure/ in $civicrm_paths['wp.backend.base']['url']  ?   There is a difference between a subdomain install - https://subdomain.example.org and if WP is in it's own directory.  Can you past your copy of the settings file that matches the one I have above?   WP in it's own directory is a special configuration.  Some hosts do it by default, other times it is set up by the organization.  Do you know who your host is?

Comment: No the lines do not have /secure/. Yes I know who my host is.  I pasted those lines on the top of my post. Does anything look out to place? WP is installed on secure.blank.org not secure.blank.org/secure/. I thought I made all the necessary configurations for the subdomain install, but if you think I missed something, let me know.